# UMDF driver for loopback joystick device

Tags: c#, c++, windows, 64-bit, umdf

I'm trying to write a UMDF device driver for a loopback (virtual) joystick device in Windows, similar to the `uinput` device in Linux.

I'm familiar with C++, C (on Linux) and C#, and the application I'm writing this for, [DroidPad](http://digitalsquid.co.uk/droidpad/), is written in C#. I've already downloaded the WDK and looked at several examples.

I decided to try the UMDF framework as I believe that user-mode drivers don't need to be signed in 64-bit windows 7; this is the problem with the joystick driver currently used by DroidPad, [PPJoy](http://ppjoy.blogspot.com/).

Any help would be greatly appreciated as to developing a UMDF driver for a virtual input device, as well as sending data to the driver from a C# application. Does anyone know of any similar UMDF driver (something similar to `uinput`)? I also read somewhere that the UMDF framework can be used from C#, how manageable would this be?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever make any progress with this?